# Assign a latitude/longitude point to a region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jvectormap

I have a map from jvectormap http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/united-kingdom/ which displays country regions in SVG 'paths'.

I also have a set of objects with latitude and longitude co-ordinates.

Is it possible to assign each object to a particular region, given the co-ordinates and the SVG paths?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing it, but it's really hackish, and I'm sure there are better ways of doing it.

Anyhow, here's my solution to the problem:

```
jvm.Map.prototype.latLngToRegion = function (lat, lng) {
        var pointOnMap = this.latLngToPoint(lat, lng),
            pointOnPage = {
                x: Math.round((pointOnMap.x + this.container.offset().left) - $(window).scrollLeft()),
                y: Math.round((pointOnMap.y + this.container.offset().top) - $(window).scrollTop())
            },
            element = document.elementFromPoint(pointOnPage.x, pointOnPage.y),
            region = $(element).attr('data-code');

        return region; // note, this will only give you the region code, but from that you can read out most of what you need from jvectormaps itself.
    }
```

Caveats are that the latitude and longitude you are looking for must be in view, for document.elementFromPoint to work. But you could maybe update the list on scroll and map pan etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can take a look at how jvectormap matches your current mouse position to the region - you should be able to match your lat/lng coordinates in a similar way